# Conditional unique validator using node, mongoose and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have this code and I want to convert the name prop in an unique model prop when role is "COMPANY" but I can't find a way to access to role value to check the condition.

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
import { IUser } from '../interfaces/user';

const validRoles = {
    values: ['HUMAN', 'COMPANY', 'RRHH'],
    message: '{VALUE} is not a valid role'
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({

    role: { type: String, required: [true, 'Role is required'], enum: validRoles },

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Name is required'],
        unique: this.role === 'COMPANY' ? true : false,
    },

    email: { type: String, required: [true, 'Email is required'], unique: true, uniqueCaseInsensitive: true },
    password: { type: String, required: [true, 'Password is required'] }

});

UserSchema.plugin( uniqueValidator, {message: '{PATH} must be unique'});

export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons that your code is not working.

1. You can't access the value of a field in the modal definition, So the code `this.role === 'COMPANY' ? true : false`, will not work in
   any case
2. When you define a field unique in mongoose it will create an index
   on that field and it is not based on conditions

Workarounds you can do:

The plugin you are using is just giving you nice error rather than an E11000 error from MongoDB when you attempt to violate a unique constraint

I suggest you create **partial unique index** in **mongoose** without the plugin

```
UserSchema.index({ name: 1 }, {
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: {
      role: { $eq: 'COMPANY' }
    }
  });
```

And handle E11000 error from MongoDB if needed